# Division and printf issue

Tags: c++

I stumbled across a problem when dividing two numbers and showing the result with `printf`. I'm getting weird numbers there.

With `std::cout` everything works fine but not with printf, why?

I always work with `printf()` as the screen output and know that one can work with `std::cout` either. (same result)

```
int a;
int b;

float z = (float)a / (float) b;
printf("%d", z);
```

Comment: What __exactly__ is the problem here? Read your question out loud. "I'm getting weird numbers there" is a terrible problem description.

Comment: When you use `%d`, the argument has to be an `int`, not `float`. There's no automatic conversion when calling variadic functions.

Comment: Presumably why `printf("%d", somefloat);` doesn't print a (sane) integer value of the float?

Comment: What does "doesn't work fine" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `printf` is a variadic function, the arguments only undergo standard conversions (e.g. `char` is converted to `int`), they aren't automatically converted to the type appropriate for the format specifier. The `%d` specifier requires that its argument be `int`, but you gave it a `float`, so the results are garbage. To print a `float` you should use `%f`:

```
printf("%f", z);
```

When you use `cout << z` this isn't necessary because `<<` uses function overloading to perform type-specific formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The way that `printf` works is that it takes "variadic parameters". This means that the arguments are not known inside printf, instead some "magic" code is used to fetch them back. `printf` uses the format string, in this case `"%d"` to determine what type the argument is - `int` in the case of `"%d"`. Since `z` is actually a `float`, it will print an integer representation of `z` - which is probably some really large number. [1]

You should fix your code to use the right format, in this case, `"%f"` seems like a good choice.

Most modern compilers also have a way to check that the format string and the actual arguments passed are matching, so you should enable warnings when you compile the code to give you a meaningful(ish) message about not passing the right argument.

[1] In x86-64 on Linux at least, float argument are passed in SSE registers, and stored in a separate lump of memory, so mismatched arguments will not print the integer representation of floats, it will print some "random" number fetched from where integers would normally have been passed.